# After reload KeyDown & Click events only working after 2nd click

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

After loading/reloading the page, the `KeyDown` and `Click` events on the `ON/OFF button` are only working after pressing it twice, not once as intended.

This is only happening the first time after loading/reloading though. The behaviour is the expected one afterwards.

I have tried `window.onload` unsuccesfully.

This is the relevant JS:

```
//Button POWER
//event listeners
buttonEl.addEventListener("click", turnOn);
window.addEventListener("keydown", checkEnterKey);
//Storing values
var greenButton = function() {
    buttonEl.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0, 103, 73, 0.4)";
    buttonEl.style.color = "white";
    buttonEl.textContent = "ON";
}
var whiteButton = function() {
    buttonEl.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7)"
    buttonEl.style.color = "rgb(40, 84, 45)";
    buttonEl.textContent = "OFF";
};
//function called on event
function turnOn(e) {
    if (buttonEl.textContent == "OFF") {
        greenButton();
        for (i = 0; i < keyEl.length; i++) {
            keyEl[i].style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0, 103, 73, 0.4)";
            pEl[i].style.color = "white";
        }
    } else {
        whiteButton();
        for (i = 0; i < keyEl.length; i++) {
            keyEl[i].style.backgroundColor = "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7)";
            pEl[i].style.color = "#2d5b3c";
        }
    }
}

function checkEnterKey(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        turnOn();
    }
}
```

Full page demo:

https://jsfiddle.net/s1rwLq3m/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is your method for determining the state of the button (`buttonEl.textContent == "OFF"`) is not very safe. In particular, the button's `textContent` initially contains some whitespace to either side of the "OFF" text, which fails the test the first time. After that, the text has been set to "OFF" with no whitespace and the test succeeds from then on.

For a quick fix, change `buttonEl.textContent` to `buttonEl.textContent.trim()`. However, I recommend using a proper boolean variable to keep track of the on/off state which doesn't rely on string comparisons.